# Meaning of かかした in this sentence さんざん無理な注文したうえに、恥までかかしたんだ

Tags: meaning, words

As per the title I am having trouble understanding かかした in this sentence:

さんざん無理な注文したうえに、恥までかかしたんだ

From my understanding from the context the sentence should mean something like:

"Not only did I completely get her to do something she didn't want, but also embarrassed her too."

All I can seem to find is 欠かす which according to jisho means:

to miss (doing); to fail (to do)

But this doesn't seem to fit in my mind.

Comment: Try searching it as 恥をかかせた instead.

Comment: Please see "shortened causative form" in [this article](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/causepass#Causative_Verbs) in case you didn't know this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

かかした in your example is the past tense form of かかす, which is a causative form of the verb かく.

かかせる is the standard/modern causative form. Its past tense form is かかせた.

かく
standard causative かかせる - past かかせた
substandard causative かかす - past かかした (← older form; used in informal situations in Kansai)

恥をかく is "embarrass oneself / feel humiliated", and 恥をかかせる/かかす means "embarrass/humiliate (someone)".

Comment: Just to add to this -- the かくhere is 掻く(scratch, perspire) (from [the Jisho definition](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%81%A5%E3%82%92%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8F).) I literally interpret this as 'oozing shame' which makes sense to me but I believe this expression is hardly ever used with the actual Kanji.